# Why Set-Cookie in the response header is ignored? using httpsCallable from @angular/fire/functions

Tags: javascript, angular, cookies, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

My goal is to store the `session` cookie, and use it to create custom token, to share auth between `subdomain1.example.com` and `subdomain2.example.com`. If the `session` cookie is missing, then when user visit `subdomain1.example.com`, it will logout.

My expected result: when I send request to Cloud Function `createSessionCookie`, it return `Set-Cookie` in the response header, then it should store the cookie in the browser.

The actual result: when I send request to Cloud Function `createSessionCookie`, the server does respond with the `Set-Cookie` header. However, when I check the DevTools > Application > Cookie, there is no `session` cookie.

The repository: https://github.com/jasonrichdarmawan/angular-firebase-authentication-across-subdomains

The domain:

1. https://account.topoint.org
2. https://experiences.topoint.org
3. https://checkout.topoint.org

Cloud Function `createSessionCookie`

```
/* eslint-disable max-len */
import {onRequest} from "firebase-functions/v2/https";
import {Request, Response} from "express";

import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires
import serviceAccountKey from "../../../serviceAccountKeys.json";


admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccountKey as admin.ServiceAccount),
});

/**
 * @todo CSRF protection
 * @bug Set-Cookie header in the response is ignored by Chrome in localhost.
 */
export const createSessionToken = onRequest(
  async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    handleCors(req, res);


    const idToken = req.body.data.idToken;

    // Set session expiration to 5 days.
    const expiresIn = 60 * 60 * 24 * 5 * 1000;

    admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken).then(function(decodedClaims) {
      // we are enforcing that the user signed in in the last 5 minutes.
      if (new Date().getTime() / 1000 - decodedClaims.auth_time < 5 * 60) {
        return admin.auth().createSessionCookie(idToken, {expiresIn: expiresIn});
      }
      throw new Error("unauthorized request");
    })
      .then(function(sessionCookie) {
        // Note httpOnly cookie will not be accessible from javascript.
        // secure flag should be set to true in production.
        const options = {
          maxAge: expiresIn,
          httpOnly: true,
          secure: process.env.FUNCTIONS_EMULATOR === "true" ? false : true, /* to test in localhost */
        };
        res.cookie("session", sessionCookie, options);
        res.send({data: "success"});
      })
      .catch(function() {
        res.status(401).send({data: "unauthorized"});
      });
  });

// eslint-disable-next-line valid-jsdoc
/**
 * @todo staging and dev environment.
 */
const handleCors = (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const allowedOrigins = ["https://account.topoint.org", "https://experiences.topoint.org", "https://checkout.topoint.org"];
  const origin = req.get("origin") ?? "";


  if (allowedOrigins.includes(origin)) {
    res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
  }

  if (process.env.FUNCTIONS_EMULATOR) {
    res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  }

  if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
    // Send response to OPTIONS requests
    res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET");
    res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization, Content-Type");
    res.set("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    res.status(204).send("");
    return;
  }
};
```

httpsCallable in Angular.

```
  /**
   * @bug Set-Cookie in the response header is ignored.
   */
  private async createSessionToken(idToken: string) {
    if (isPlatformServer(this.platformId)) { return; }

    const callable = httpsCallable<{idToken: string}>(this.functions, "createSessionToken",);
    const { data } = await callable({idToken: idToken});
  }
```

2nd Version:

using Angular's HttpClient

```
  /**
   * @bug Set-Cookie in the response header is ignored.
   */
  private async createSessionToken(idToken: string) {
    if (isPlatformServer(this.platformId)) { return; }

    // const callable = httpsCallable<{idToken: string}>(this.functions, "createSessionToken",);
    // const { data } = await callable({idToken: idToken});

    const observable = this.httpClient.post(
      "http://127.0.0.1:5001/topoint-org/asia-east1/createSessionToken",
      {
        data: {
          idToken: idToken,
        }
      }
    )

    observable.subscribe(response => {
      console.log(response);
    });
  }
```

The server respond with the `Set-Cookie` header, but in the `DevTools > Application > Cookie`, there is no `session` cookie.

[image]

**3rd Version**

I noticed that `httpsCallable` is using `POST` instead of `GET`. So, I created a Cloud Function `setCookie`, and if I visit the link directly, it will store the Cookie. If I send a request using `httpsCallable` or Angular's `HttpClient`, it will not store the cookie.

Note: I am starting to believe that it's an Angular issue.

functions/src/features/hello-world/set-cookie/set-cookie.ts

```
/* eslint-disable max-len */
import {onRequest} from "firebase-functions/v2/https";

export const setCookie = onRequest((req, res) => {
  const sessionCookie = (Math.random()* 100000000000000000).toString();

  // Set session expiration to 5 days.
  const expiresIn = 60 * 60 * 24 * 5 * 1000;
  const options = {
    maxAge: expiresIn,
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: process.env.FUNCTIONS_EMULATOR === "true" ? false : true, /* to test in localhost */
  };
  res.cookie("session", sessionCookie, options);
  res.send({data: "Set Cookie"});
});
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "However, it is not stored in the browser"?  What are you doing to observe that the result is something other than what you expect?  Please edit the question to be clear.  There should be enough instruction in the question that anyone can use the duplicate and observe the result.

Comment: I'm noticing that you've mixed up [HTTP functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events?gen=2nd) with [callable functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable?gen=2nd).  You've authored an HTTP function, but you're invoking it as a callable function.  Are you doing that intentionally?  Normally you don't invoke an HTTP function this way.  You just use fetch or axios to make an HTTP request.

Comment: @DougStevenson I mean that I see the Set Cookie in the response header but the cookie is not saved when I open the DevTools and go to the cookie section, there is no`session` cookoe. I will edit the question. I did not do that intentionally. I was assuming that this is the @angular/fire way.

Comment: The only real "way" is to have the frontend and backend match technology stacks as you see in the documentation.  There is nothing terribly appropriate about mixing HTTP and callable without a clear reason. It's actually a very common mistake and causes all kinds of problem for people - the problems end up on SO on a regular basis.

Comment: @DougStevenson I am relying on Firebase Emulators to develop the cloud function, so `httpsCallable` is kind of "ease of use". Are you sure this is because of `httpsCallable` and not because of my wrong implementation in Cloud Function?

Comment: No. I just point this out because you have a clear and common mismatch between types that's known to cause posts on Stack Overflow.  It's up to you to decide if you code meets whatever standards you hold for correctness and readability.

Comment: @DougStevenson `because you have a clear and common mismatch between types that's known to cause posts on Stack Overflow`. I see, so this is a common question. Anyway, it's not caused by Cloud Function, I created a simple Cloud Function `setCookie`, when I tried to send request with `httpsCallable` or Angular's `HttpClient`, it will ignore the `Set-Cookie` header. Meanwhile, if I visit the Cloud Function `setCookie` directly, the browser will store the cookie.